# Two events on a single button in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I'm trying to create a button which can have two events on a single button so that I can add and remove a marker, I can do it with jQuery but can't work it out in react.

```
var Button = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
           name: 'add marker'
        };
    },
    render: function() {
        return <button type="button" onClick={this.onClick}>{this.state.name}</button>
    },

    onClick: function(ev) {
    // event 1
        alert('marker added');
    
    // event 2
        alert('remove marker');
        this.setState({name:'markert removed'})
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zidski/5z3f7zL4/1/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to use the same button to add/remove a marker, then you can do something like this:

```
var Button = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
      return {
        marker: false
      };
    },
    onClick: function() {
        this.setState({
            marker: !this.state.marker
        });
    },
    render: function() {
      return <button type="button" onClick={this.onClick}>{this.state.marker ? 'Add marker' : 'Remove marker'}</button>
    }
});
```

Store a boolean value and update that when clicking the button. You can manage the buttons text based off that boolean.

Answer (score 0):

you can access to the element with `event.target`,
if you would set the value of the button to something like 'add' or 'remove' you can capture it via event.target.value

for ex.

```
handleClick(event) {
    let actionType = event.target.value; // 'add' or 'remove', now you can control the flow with switch case or regular if's */
}
render(){
    return (<button value='add' onClick={this.handleClick}>{name}</button>)
}
```